# How to put conditions within the lambda in python3

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, conditional-statements

I want to make a lambda corresponding to the signum function in python.

i have tried the following ways

```
f = lambda x: if x>=0 1 else -1
```

Then, i want to plot this curve.
my code is -

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.arange(-10,10)
y=f(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

By this, I am not getting the desired result. Pls suggest a way in which this can be achieved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> f = lambda x: 1 if x>=0  else -1
>>> f(1)
1
>>> f(-2)
-1
```